# Blank screen after onPause-onResume

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing an android game using OpenGL ES 2.0. Some of my users (about 5%) face such problem: after locking/unlocking device or after pressing home button and resuming the app gray screen appears. I mean this happens after calling onResume and onPause.

Screen is gray because background is filled with this color:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1f);
```

This means than after resuming the app nothing is drawn on some phones.

I'm using virtual buffer objects (upload all buffers to GPU). They are recreated after onResume same as all textures and shaders.

Also I'm calling surfaceView.onPause and .onResume in activity's onPause and onResume.

I can't understand why my app is not drawing anything after resuming on some phones (when on the majority of phones everything is ok) and I hope that someone can give me several ideas about why this can happen.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But I do have one line in LogCat `E/BpSurfaceComposerClient: Failed to transact (-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide us with some logcat output, but looks like part of your rendering path is being skipped (maybe because there is an exception in your rendering loop code). Without further data is really hard for us to help you with this specific problem.

Comment: Problem is that there aren't any messages in logcat. Following logcat everything is fine.